# Calling the same animation with different values when it's completed

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to do different manipulations on `Label` inside Table in `libGDX`.

in my `Table` class I create a `Label` and `scale\move\rotate` it, I'm trying to call to this actions every time the actions is finishes so each time It will run on different string, but I got a crash because of calling to my self every time (i think).

```
a= new Label("", mLabelStyleAmount);
addActor(a);   // in a Table class

    action = Actions.run(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                lunchText(i);
            }
        });

private void lunchText (int i) {
    a.setText(strings[i]); 
    ScaleToAction up = Actions.scaleBy(30, 20, 5)
    a.setPosition(a.getWidth() * 0.2f, 50);
    a.addAction(Actions.sequence(up, action));
    i++;

}
```

Is this is the right way to call the same method each time I finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you've got is being caused by **infinite recurrence** that being caused by adding `action` in method that is being fired by `action` :) It means that every time you add the `action` to your action you add `action` again and so on and so on...

Second thing is that when you are adding many action by using `addAction` method these actions are **parallel** not **sequential**!

The resolution is to use libGDX `SequenceAction` and to generate all `action` at the beginning. It should like:

```
    SequenceAction sequence = Actions.sequence();

    for(int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        sequence.addAction(Actions.run(new Runnable() {
                                             @Override
                                             public void run() {
                                                a.setText(strings[i]); 
                                                a.setPosition(a.getWidth() * 0.2f, 50);                                                            
                                             }
                                        }, Actions.scaleBy(30, 20, 5)));
```

Another way is to check in `render()` method if `a` do not have any actions (what means that last actions is finished) and then add new action

```
    //render()
    if(a.getActions.size == 0)
        addActionToA();
```